# Optimized query for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have following table in my SQL Server database:

```
| ID   | Class                                             | CId   | PId 
| 7865 | Add Class for Prop                                | 1043  | 1 
|   82 | Advanced Carpet Spotting Advanced Carpet Spotting | 1043  | 1 
|   82 | Advanced Carpet Spotting Advanced Carpet Spotting | 1042  | 1 
| 7863 | aTesting                                          | 1042  | 0 
| 7218 | aUnique                                           | 1042  | 0 
|   85 | Body Mechanics                                    | 1042  | 1 
|   88 | Carpet Bonnet Cleaning                            | 1044  | 0 
|   89 | Carpet Shampooing/Extraction                      | 1044  | 1 
| 7829 | Class 10                                          | 1044  | 0
```

I have multiple `CId` and `PId`

If distinct `CId` have their corresponding `PId = 1` Then,

```
Set CId = 1 Otherwise 0
```

I want output like this

```
|  CId | Status | Count  
| 1042 |   0    |   4 
| 1043 |   1    |   2 
| 1044 |   0    |   3
```

I can get required output by using multiple queries but I want more optimized one .

Please suggest a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please review your question: (1) You are resetting the value of `CId` (not sure that was your intension), (2) Where is `Status` coming from? Also, present your current solution and explain what is the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cid, 
       case when count(case when pid = 1 then 1 end) > 0 
            then 1 
            else 0 
       end as status, 
       count(*) as count
from your_table
group by cid
```

Answer (score 0):

If `PId` is always `1` and `0`, you can do the following.

```
SELECT
    CID,
    AVG([Status] * 1) AS [Status],
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    CID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether the sum of PId is equal to count of PId.

**Query**

```
select [CId], 
case when sum([Cid]) = count([CId]) then 1 
else 0 end as [Status],
count([CId]) as [Count]
from [your_table_name]
group by [CId];
```

Also `PId` should have only 1 and 0 values.